# Change merge pull into rebase pull

Tags: git, github, version-control, merge, rebase

It is now possible to rebase when accepting pull requests on GitHub, thus making no merge commits. Is it possible to convert my older accepted pull request to rebase instead then merge, so there is no merge commit in the history?

Comment: If you're already merged it, then no

Comment: Can I rebase my commit history locally and force push to the remote to achieve the same effect?

Comment: Yes, but you'll rewrite any commit history after the first commit that you change - if you're the only one using the repository then that's OK, but it'll be a pain for anyone else using it

Comment: I'm the only one. How can I do so?

Comment: Read up on `git rebase`

Comment: I know how to use it, but whenever I do `git rebase -i <first commit hash>`, I do not see the merge commit in the text file that opens.

Comment: Merge commits are automatically removed when you rebase, unless you tell it to include them. Really all you need to do is continue without doing anything and it will remove all the merge commits

Comment: Found it. To anyone who stumbles here, the command line argument to use is: `-p`

Comment: You should write an answer with your findings in it - might be useful to others in future\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `git rebase -i <first commit hash> -p` and simply drop the merge commit(s), then force push.

The `-p` argument is required, or else Git will hide merge commits during the rebase.